# Chroma key in php using ImageMagic extension for php

Tags: php, linux, centos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Im trying to use the ImageMagick library in order to chorma key an image programmaticly in php. So far i've installed the ImageMagick extension onto my server and made sure it is working using some simple commands in the terminal itself. My goal is to get this working as php code but currently im just trying to find a script that works for me. My problem is that I cant get the greenscreen script from fred's imagemagick scripts to work. when trying to excute the scripti get a `file does not exist or is not an ordinary file not readable or has zero size` error.
The same is true when I try to use *any* of the imagemagick/fred's scripts on php.
I've tried:

In php:

- giving everything 777 permissions
- specifying full paths from the root directory of the server
- chagning the temp dir within the script itself

In the terminal:

- works with regular scripts though didn't find a script the does real life chroma key
- can't make it use freds scripts

Update: Got the Imagemagick fred's script to work in the terminal though the image is returned in black and white. currently working on getting it to work as php code using `exec()`

Update 2: using this exec on my php
`exec("/bin/bash /home/full_path_within_server/public_html/imagemagictest/greenscreen.sh shirt.jpg t.png",$out,$returnval);`

I get the following error message: "FILE shirt.jpg DOES NOT EXIST OR IS NOT AN ORDINARY FILE, NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO"

Comment: Who is "fred" and what are his scripts?

Comment: Please note that if using my scripts or rewriting them for commercial applications, then you must contact me about a license. Please read the header in the file and on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. My contact info is on the home page. If your images are not in your working directory (the one with the php file) or if they are in the same directory as the script, then you will need to provide the full path to them. Contact me offline, if you still have issues. Note you have not provide arguments to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, change the all instances of the convert in the script to the full path of the convert function.

Comment: Please note that if using my scripts or rewriting them for commercial applications, then you must contact me about a license. Please read the header in the file and on my home page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. My contact info is on the home page. If your images are not in your working directory (the one with the php file) or if they are in the same directory as the script, then you will need to provide the full path to them. Contact me offline, if you still have issues. Note you have not provide arguments to the script.